# Finding the slowest decay to a value for a 2D function

Tags: equation-solving, functions, mathematical-optimization, constraint

I have a function `acf2[x,y]` that describes the auto-correlation function of a simulated real surface, with a peak at the origin (`acf2[0,0] = 1`), and need to find the maximum distance from the origin that the function value first drops to `acf2[x,y] = 1/5`. A simple example of the function is

$$acf2(x,y)=\frac{1}{4} \left(e^{-31250 i \pi  x}+e^{31250 i \pi  x}+e^{-62500 i \pi  y}+e^{62500 i \pi  y}\right)$$

for a surface of size $-32\times 10^{-6} \leq x,y \leq 32\times 10^{-6}$.

Using the `Nmaximize` function, in the form

```
NMaximize[{Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], Re[acf2[x, y]] >= 1/5 && lowerbound <= x <= upperbound && lowerbound <= y <= upperbound}, {x, y}]
```

where `upperbound` and `lowerbound` define the boundaries of the surface, results in mathematica obtaining a position for which `acf2[x,y] >= 1/5` near the boundaries of the surface. This is the expected result, but not what I am trying to find. Instead, I need to obtain the furthest distance the function *first* drops to 1/5. In other words, the furthest distance on the first countour line of `acf[x,y] = 1/5` that encloses the origin.

The way I have attempted to solve this is by saying "all the values of `acf2[x,y]` on the straight line between the maximum position and the origin must be >= 1/5". Attempting to implement this I have converted the function to cylindrical coordinates

```
acf2polar[r_, theta_] = acf2[x, y] /. {x -> r*Cos[theta], y -> r*Sin[theta]};
```

and added my condition as a constraint:

```
NMaximize[{r, Re[acf2polar[Interval[{0, r}], theta]] >= 1/5 }, {r, theta}]
```

using `Interval[{0,r}]` to try and specify I need to constraint to hold for the whole line between `r` and the origin.

However, running this returns an error that the constraints aren't valid and that 'constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain specifications involving the variables'.

Am I on the right lines here, or is there another method I should be using?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be worth doing this in some sense "by eye". Consider this: `ContourPlot[
 Re[acf2[x, y]], {x, -32 10^-6, 32 10^-6}, {y, -32 10^-6, 32 10^-6}
 , ContourShading -> False, Contours -> {1/5}]`. This generates a contour plot where the contours are the curves where `Re[acf2[x, y]] == 1/5`. It looks to me like you have to move in the `x` direction to move toward the farthest point at which the function drops to 1/5.

Comment: Hi march, thanks for the reply. I've already had a look at using `ContourPlot`, and unfortunately trying to extract `[x,y]` values from the plotted points doesn't give very accurate results, due to the limited number of points plotted on the graph. The application of the problem requires a fairly high degree of accuracy, and so I think a mathematical approach is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to find the maximal radius for each angle, and then optimize over the angle. I also repeat your definitions for completeness.

```
acf2[x_, y_] := 1/4 (E^(-31250 I π x) + E^(31250 I π x) + 
                     E^(-62500 I π y) + E^(62500 I π y));
acf2polar[r_, theta_] := acf2[x, y] /. {x -> r*Cos[theta], y -> r*Sin[theta]};
InThatDirection[theta_?NumericQ] := s /. FindRoot[Re[acf2polar[s, theta] - 1/5], {s, 0}, 
   Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> {"TrustRegion",
              "StartingScaledStepSize" -> 0.001}}];
```

The function `InThatDirection` finds the first root of `acf2polar[s,theta]-1/5` for a given value of theta. Note that I had to change the trust region, because otherwise `FindRoot` would skip over the first root (so keep this in mind when you apply this approach to other correlation functions).
Now we can maximize the radius over all angles:

```
NMaximize[{InThatDirection[theta], 0 < theta < 2 π}, theta, Method -> "RandomSearch"]
```

> {0.0000225546, {theta -> 1.64376*10^-9}}

Or if you want to get the point:

```
p = #[[1]] {Cos[theta], Sin[theta]} /. #[[2]] &@%
```

> {0.0000225546, 3.70743*10^-14}

Comment: This solves the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear it worked for you! You can also accept the answer to express that.